# jquery how get and makes array of input classes value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have numbers of `input` with same classes, now I want to create an array based on it but I don't have any idea. This will not use the `name` tag of the `input`. this is my html code:

```
<input type="text" class="option" value='1'>
<input type="text" class="option" value='2'>
<input type="text" class="option" value='3a'>
...
<input type="text" class="option" value='43'>
<input type="text" class="option" value='6y'>
```

this will be multiple that I cannot determine the exact number of the input fields.

Now I want to create in `jquery` or `javascript` array to get those value but I dont have any idea.

I tried this code but only gets the last input value and not all the value.

```
     var arrs = [];
    jQuery('.option').each(function(){
        arrs.push(jQuery(this).val());
    });
    var arrayLength = arrs.length;
    var retval = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        retval = arrs[i] + '|';
        //Do something
    }
    alert(retval);
```

Comment: you need to append the string inside for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the last value becuase

```
retval = arrs[i] + '|';
```

you replace your string everytime

try like this

```
retval += arrs[i] + '|';
```

You don't need loop to join

try like this

```
var retval = arrs.join("|");
alert(retval)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ru3ymvc5/2/

```
retval = arrs[i] + '|';
```

This should be

```
retval += arrs[i] + '|';
```

Adding the + operator makes sure the previous values are not overwritten with the last value.

You could also avoid the loop entirely by using the join method of Array;

```
var retval = "";
retval = arrs.join("|");
```

[Working JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru3ymvc5/2/)

Comment: Based on the answer of @anik-islam-abhi, I modified the fiddle to use join instead of looping through the array;